# File upload - only current files in current directory will work

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, file-upload

below is a snippet of my code.

What I'm trying to achieve is that user can upload a csv/txt file and then a table will show up. For some reason when I tested my code below, it will only work if the csv file was in the directory. When I tried on other csv/txt files that are not in the directory nothing happened.

I can't figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript"charset="utf-8">

 $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#myfile").change(function(){


     var path = $("#myfile").val(),
     file = path.split('\\').pop();

     d3.text(file, function (datasetText) {

           ...........
          .........
       });

    });

  });   


</script>
</head>
<body>



  <input type="file" id="myfile">


  </body>
  <html>
```

Comment: `file = path.split('\\').pop();`.  You're only getting the filename.  That assumes it's in the same folder.  If it's in a different folder, you're gonna need the path.

Comment: I did that because -  d3.text(file, function (datasetText)  - the first argument accepts something like "File.csv" If I put the whole path the processing of csv doesn't happen. How do I go about this? @RocketHazmat

Comment: That was just a guess.  Sorry that didn't fix it :-P